# Authorization Lambda caching based on api-key and path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an Authorization Lambda for my API Gateway.

This Lambda will take an api-key in the header, and the event.path, that is, the requested path, and based on this combination will either allow the request to proceed or return a 403 Forbidden.

I want to enable Authorization Caching, however, it's not clear to me how the keys in the cache are formed. I want the cache key to consider both the api-key and the requested path, how can I do this?